# Create a stringstream duplicate

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

I know I cannot copy a `stringstream`, but I am wondering if I can duplicate it so that I can create two strings with similar output specifiers.

Something like this

```
std::stringstream s1;
s1 << std::scientific << std::setprecision(4);
s1 << 0.01;

// Later on I want to create s2 given s1
std::stringstream s2;
// Copy formatting specifiers from s1 to s2, so that the effect is 
// s2 << std::scientific << std::setprecision(4);
s2 << 0.02;
```

My reason is that I am writing a function that takes a stringstream and I would like to know the width of some output before modifying the stringstream.

I have looked through most of the question on `stringstream` here and I couldn't find an answer to this specific case.

Comment: Look at the stream's [`copyfmt()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/copyfmt) method: "*copies the state of the stream `other` into `*this`.*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `copyfmt` - copy formatting information.

```
s2.copyfmt(s1);
```

Alternatively you could save and restore flags with:

```
std::ios_base::fmtflags f = s1.flags();
s2.flags(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`copyfmt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/copyfmt) method inherited from `std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>`.